# How retrive full path with file name or folder name from ShellTreeView/ShellListView

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

Sir,
I create a project, where I use **ShellTreeView**, **ShellListView**, **ListView**. Now I drag folder from ShellTreeView and files from ShellListView. Now I want to retrieve file name including full path (like: c:\abc\file.txt) or folder (like C:\abc).
For retrieving the path I use a command button and a text box.
What will the code?

Dev

Comment: What component library are you using?  Delphi 2010 doesn't come with any controls called ShellTreeView or ShellListView.

Comment: @Mason the controls exist in this path `C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\7.0\Demos\DelphiWin32\VCLWin32\ShellControls` in Delphi 2010.

Answer (score 8):

you can use the `TShellListView.SelectedFolder` and `TShellTreeView.Path` properties to retrieve the path and filename selected.

this sample uses the onchange event and assign the path into an EditText.

```
procedure TForm1.ShellListView1Change(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem;
  Change: TItemChange);
begin
  Edit2.Text := ShellListView1.SelectedFolder.PathName;
end;

procedure TForm1.ShellTreeView1Change(Sender: TObject; Node: TTreeNode);
begin
 Edit1.Text:= ShellTreeView1.Path;
end;
```